# Show animation on click in an Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-animation

Im new to Android development, and would like to consult the community on one thing.

I would like to show a small animation whenever a user clicks one of my buttons.
Something like small fireworks, star sprinkles or something like that, just to give the user an confirmation that the button is clicked.

I immediatly think of throwing up an animated gif, but after some searching I found out that it is a bit hard in Android.

What are my options on this issue, and what would be considered best practice perfomance wise?

Comment: You can create your own animation drawable in android. Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html and see if that is what you're looking for

Comment: twin animation, frame by frame, alpha such animation are there, try to search on it.

Comment: You might find Xamarin's document on [Graphics and Animation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/graphics_and_animation) helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried on touch, you could do on click as well. 
see the below code.

Make images for your animation and keep in a folder in png format.
Animate those images with code below.

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rocket_thrust3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Then
    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    rocketAnimation.start();
    return true;
}
 return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is worth looking into. Just have to make my own animation then I guess :P